# Android Animations similar to make marquee vertical

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, textview, marquee

Apologies for this basic question, as I'm a complete novice to Android:

I can make my `TextView` scroll horizontally on one line.

But what I need is multiple `TextViews`, which in a marquee fashion all scroll **vertically** to the bottom of the screen and then back up to the top.

I've been searching for hours and cannot see anything in the android API that seems to do this.

Or is there an animation feature that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this [GitHub Project](https://github.com/tbdawg/VerticalMarqueeTextView/tree/master/VMTV_Example) it has a wonderful example in it too.

**Edit:**
make your xml some thing like this:

```
<com.package.project.VerticalMarqueeTextView
android:id="@+id/vmTextView"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/vmtvText"
android:minLines="1"
android:maxLines="10"
android:width="250dp"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

In your activity class:

```
private VerticalMarqueeTextView _txtView1; //declare a member variable
```

In `onCreate()`:

```
_txtView1 = (VerticalMarqueeTextView) findViewById(R.id.mTextView1);
_txtView1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

And in other activity lifecycle methods:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    // Start or restart the Marquee if paused.
    if (_txtView1.isPaused()) {
        _txtView1.resumeMarquee();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    // Pause the Marquee when the Activity pauses.
    _txtView1.pauseMarquee();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    _txtView1.stopMarquee();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it still scrolls horizontally on one line not vertically down to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: i have updated my answer, check out that example, you just have to add that class to you project, define the textview like they have defined, and in `onCreate()` just `VerticalMarqueeTextView _textview1 = (VerticalMarqueeTextView) findViewById(R.id.vmTextView);`
`_textview1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`, you can use `stopMarquee()` `pauseMarquee()` `resumeMarquee()`

Comment: Thanks so I just need that `VerticalMarqueeTextView` added to my project and then make reference it in `onCreate()` etc?

Comment: yes, you are right.. and dont forget to make your textview xml as `<com.package.project.VerticalMarqueeTextView ..... />`