# Android button text vertical scrolling

Tags: android, button, scroll

I'm developing an android app and on one screen I have 10 square buttons. The text on some buttons is too long to be displayed so at the moment only a portion of it shows. What I want to do is have the buttons' text scroll vertically (within the button) automatically when the button is not in focus. So the screen loads up and the text scrolls indefinitely. Everytime it reaches the end it should start from the beginning of the text and scroll downwards again. I know that there is a marquee attribute and this can be achieved horizontally but I need it vertically. I have researched the scrollTo method but it instantly scrolls to the bottom. I would post some code but whatever I have is from other SO posts. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731123/android-animations-similar-to-make-marquee-vertical

Comment: Thanks brokenstar! I will give it a go and report back.

Answer (score 0):

@brokenstar supplied a link that really helped me. I had to make some modifications in order to address my specific needs so here's the modified code.

```
public class SquareButtonVScrolling extends SquareButton {

private boolean stop;
private boolean isNotDrawn = true;
private final Activity activity;
private long duration;
private int pixelYOffSet;

public SquareButtonVScrolling(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this.activity = (Activity) context;
}

public SquareButtonVScrolling(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    this.activity = (Activity) context;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, width);
}

public void init() {
    // If there are more lines than can be displayed startMarquee, otherwise don't do anything
    if ((SquareButtonVScrolling.this).getLineCount() > (SquareButtonVScrolling.this).getHeight() / (SquareButtonVScrolling.this).getLineHeight()) {
        setDuration(65l);
        setPixelYOffSet(1);

        stop = false;

        startMarquee();
    }
}

/**
 * @return Returns the (long) duration in milliseconds between calls to the
 *         next scrollBy(0, pixelYOffSet).
 */
public long getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

/**
 * @param duration
 *            Sets the (long) duration in milliseconds between calls to the
 *            next scrollBy(0, pixelYOffSet). Defaults to 65L if value is
 *            less than or equal to 0.
 */
public void setDuration(long duration) {
    if (duration <= 0) {
        this.duration = 65l;
    } else {
        this.duration = duration;
    }
}

/**
 * @return Returns the (int) amount of Y pixels to scroll by.
 */
public int getPixelYOffSet() {
    return pixelYOffSet;
}

/**
 * @param pixelYOffSet
 *            Sets the (int) amount of Y pixels to scroll by. Defaults to 1
 *            if value is less.
 */
public void setPixelYOffSet(int pixelYOffSet) {
    if (pixelYOffSet < 1) {
        this.pixelYOffSet = 1;
    } else {
        this.pixelYOffSet = pixelYOffSet;
    }
}

/**
 * Starts the marquee
 */
private void startMarquee() {
    new AutoScrollSquareButton().executeOnExecutor(Utils.CUSTOM_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}

/**
 * Stop the marquee.
 */
public void stopMarquee() {
    stop = true;
}

private class AutoScrollSquareButton extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private int pixelCount;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Check to see if the VMSB has been drawn to get proper sizing.
        while (squareButtonNotDrawn()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

            while (!stop) {
                // Sleep duration amount between scrollBy pixelYOffSet
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(duration);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            // if VMSB has reached or exceeded the last
                            // Y pixel scroll back to top
                            if ((SquareButtonVScrolling.this).getScrollY() >= pixelCount) {
                                (SquareButtonVScrolling.this).scrollTo(0, 0);

                            } else { // Otherwise scroll by the pixelYOffSet
                                (SquareButtonVScrolling.this).scrollBy(0, pixelYOffSet);
                            }

                            (SquareButtonVScrolling.this).invalidate();
                    }
                });
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    private boolean squareButtonNotDrawn() {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Checks to see if VMSB has been drawn.
                if ((SquareButtonVScrolling.this).isShown()) {
                    // Calculate the total pixel height that needs to be scrolled.
                    // May need additional calculations if there is additional padding.
                    pixelCount = (SquareButtonVScrolling.this).getLineHeight() * (SquareButtonVScrolling.this).getLineCount();
                    isNotDrawn = false;
                }
            }
        });

        return isNotDrawn;
    }
}
```

}

When calling the init() function you need to make sure that getLineCount(), getHeight() and getLineHeight() will return the required values and not 0. These functions need to be called after the views have been drawn so in my case I called init() like this:

```
myView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myView.init();
                }
            }, 20);
```

The small delay of 20ms was enough. Also, because I had up to 30 vertically auto-scrolling buttons I needed to use executeOnExecutor for starting the AsyncTask with a custom thread pool (in order to have multiple buttons scrolling at the same time). Here's the definition I used:

```
/**
     * A custom {@link Executor} that can be used to execute tasks in parallel.
     */
    public static final Executor CUSTOM_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR = new ThreadPoolExecutor(30, 30, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128));
```

Hope this helps someone!